# How can I capture "search" but not "/search" in RegEx WITHOUT lookarounds?

Tags: regex, google-bigquery

BigQuery Standard SQL doesn't allow for lookarounds, and I've been struggling with how to "get around" that limitation. If I wanted to capture "search" but not "/search", with lookarounds I would use the RegEx `(?<!\/)search` Any suggestions for doing this without lookarounds?

Answer (score 1):

See example below

```
#standardSQL
WITH example AS (
  SELECT 'search' text UNION ALL
  SELECT '/search' 
)
SELECT text, 
  REGEXP_CONTAINS(text, r'(?:^|[^/])search') match
FROM example
```

with output

```
Row text    match    
1   search  true     
2   /search false
```